# glGetShaderiv returns value greater than 1

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to compile my shader in OpenGLES 2.0:

```
/* Try compiling the shader. */
GL_CHECK(glCompileShader(*pShader));
GL_CHECK(glGetShaderiv(*pShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &iStatus));
```

glGetShaderiv returns iStatus greater than 1 and when I try to get log info I get empty string:

```
if (iStatus > 1)
{
    GLsizei slen = 0;
    GLchar* compiler_log = (GLchar*)malloc(iStatus);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(*pShader, iStatus, &slen, compiler_log);
    cout <<"compiler_log:\n"<<compiler_log<<endl;
    free (compiler_log);
}
```

Shader:

```
attribute vec4 av4position;
attribute vec3 av3colour;
attribute vec2 av2texture;

uniform mat4 mvp;

varying vec3 vv3colour;
varying vec2 vv2texture;

void main() 
{
  // Pass the texture coordinate attribute to a varying.
  vv2texture = av2texture;
  // Pass the color value to a varying.
  vv3colour = av3colour;
  gl_Position = mvp * av4position;
}
```

Does anybody has any idea why?

Comment: So did you just abandon this question after solving it yourself or do you have any further questions regarding the already posted answers?

Comment: I just solved it today, I'll reformat my question and add an answer after work.

Comment: Still waiting for that solution, different from the already exisiting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glGetShaderiv didn't return value greater than 1, it didn't return anything (variable was not initialized).

The reason it didn't return anything is that there were no packages installed:

libglapi-mesa
libgl1-mesa-glx
libgl1-mesa-dri

which are not available on Ubuntu 11.04, only on Ubuntu 11.10. So I wasn't able to find solution for 11.04, I just upgraded to 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by [`GL_COMPILE_STATUS`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShader.xml) is not the same as the length of the info log. It is just an indicator if the shader was compiled successfully or not, so it should actually be either `GL_TRUE` or `GL_FALSE`. But I guess a value > 1 can be counted as successful (since your shader also looks completely reasonable), too, so no need to get the info log anyway, which may just be an empty string in case of a successful compilation.

To get the length of the info log, call

```
glGetShaderiv(*pShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &iLength)
```

and use this value for allocating and querying the info log. So your code should look something like:

```
if (iStatus == GL_FALSE)
{
    GLsizei iLength, slen = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(*pShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &iLength);
    GLchar* compiler_log = new GLchar[iLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(*pShader, iLength, &slen, compiler_log);
    cout << "compiler_log:\n" << compiler_log << endl;
    delete[] compiler_log;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, if an error is generated, no change is made to the value of the parameter (the last argument to glGetShaderiv).

To better debug the issue, use glGetError() before shader compilation.